# Regresion Coeffients and Estimated Marginal Means in Glmm

Tags: glmm, lsmeans

What is the relationship between regression coefficients for categorical variables and their estimated marginal means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regression coefficients may be used to make predictions. Marginal averages of such predictions over a regular grid produce estimated marginal means.

Comment: In the case of a categorical variable, shouldn't it be possible to calculate the estimated means from each treatment using the coefficients. If you get predicted means from coefficients, would they aggree with the estimated marginal means? If not, why?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. That's what is stated in my answer. Follow those two steps: (1) make predictions for each factor combination; these are of the form A*b for some matrix A, where b is the vector of regression coefficients. (2) Obtain marginal averages of those predictions. That is equivalent to averaging together the corresponding rows of A. The resulting averaged rows of A give you the linear functions of the regression coefficients corresponding to the EMMs.

Comment: See the vignette on basics of EMMs: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/basics.html

Comment: Thanks Russ, that helps. I had read through the vignette but I didn't find as succinct and clear an explanation. I'm trying to decide if I should plot EMMs in response scale, or coefficients in response scale.

Comment: It makes no sense to put the coefficients on the response scale. They are only coefficients for the linear predictor -- not the predictions themselves.

Comment: Yes, for continuous variables. But why not for a categorical variables? You have a reference level, then predicted change in other levels. Interpreting them in terms of response scale is very often done... no?

Comment: Why not, indeed? Are you talking about a categorical RESPONSE variable? Then the predictions come out on a logit (or other link function) scale. You can back-transform the emms to the original scale. There are tons of examples in those vignettes - please look at them and note there is a topic index too.